# creating message component (Button) discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

[image: component]

Click at this

I want to create button but I don't know how can I do it? Can anybody give me an example? I want it without packages

Comment: Click Button is release with discord.js v13 but it not official yet you have to wait for stable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with no modules (just discord.js) to create a simple button and reply on click:

```js
const { Client, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js')

// The code... (the client.on('message') or .on('interactionCreate'))

    const row = new MessageActionRow()
      .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
          .setCustomId("simple-example") // It is better to have a unique ID for the buttons
          .setLabel("Text diplayed on the button")
          .setStyle('PRIMARY'), //PRIMARY, SECONDARY, ALERT or SUCCESS
      );
      
      // For interactions do like this:
      interaction.reply({ content: "Super button below", components: [row] })
      // For messages do like this:
      message.reply({ content: "Super button below", components: [row] })
     
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "simple-example") {
            interaction.reply('Button clicked !')
        }
    }
})
// Log in with the bot
```

Comment: For a LINK style you can't reply to the button interaction but you need to specify the .setURL('http://example.com')